# Cannot install Nvidia drivers Ubuntu-Server 16.04

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics

I cannot install nvidia drivers for RTX 2080 (nvidia-410) on Ubuntu-Server 16.04.

Commands executed:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-410

sudo reboot
```

After the reboot I expect `nvidia-smi` to work, but the output of it when running it is

```
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

The ultimate goal is to install Tensorflow with CUDA support.

EDIT:

I tried to do

```
cd /
sudo apt purge nvidia*

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update

sudo apt install nvidia-430
sudo reboot
```

After the reboot I tried to execute `nvidia-smi`, but I got the error message:

```
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

(same as before)

Comment: Disable Secure Boot, purge those drivers that are now obsoleted, add the graphics drivers PPA and install the latest version, at the time of this writing 430.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I attempted your solution. Disabled Secure Boot in the BIOS settings, and ran the following commands:

```sudo apt purge nvidia*```, ```sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa```, ```sudo apt install nvidia-430```. 

But the same issue prevails.

Comment: You need to `sudo apt update` after adding the PPA. Please [edit] the question with that update and also post any error messages in full.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I tried it again, but using ```sudo apt update``` after adding the repositories, and got the same error.